# API call to bigquery.jobs.insert failed with error: Empty response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am uploading a CSV file to Big Query and getting this error message:
API call to bigquery.jobs.insert failed with error: Empty response

I have just done 2 normal executions, after finishing the code on Google Apps Script, and than the code started to give me this error message with absolutely no clue about what is happening.

This is the code I am using:

```
function CargaBigQuery(BQDatasetId, BQTableId, BQFileBlob) {
  // ================================================================================
  // Insert .csv file on Google BigQuery.
  //
  // [BQDatasetId] = Dataset on BigQuery
  // [BQTableId] = Table on Dataset
  // [BQFileBlob] = Blob of CSV file
  // ================================================================================

  const projectId = 'xxxxxx';
  BQFileBlob.setContentType('application/octet-stream');

  const job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: BQDatasetId,
          tableId: BQTableId
        },
        skip_leading_rows: 1,
        field_delimiter: ';',
        encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
        allow_jagged_rows: true,
        allow_quoted_new_lines: true,
        autodetect: false,
        ignore_unknown_values: false,
        source_format: 'CSV',
        write_disposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
        max_bad_records: 0
      }
    }
  };

  try {
    const jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, BQFileBlob);
    console.log(`\t\tLoading status: ${jobResult.status.state}`);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('\t\tError: ' + err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

It is a compressed file with only one .csv file inside.
The function call is like this:

```
var Escopo = {};
Escopo.DatasetId = 'aaaaaaaaa';
Escopo.TableId = 'bbbbbbbbb';
FileID = 'google drive .zip file ID';

var ArqZip = DriveApp.getFileById(FileID).getBlob();
ArqZip.setContentType("application/zip");
var ArqUnZipped = Utilities.unzip(ArqZip);
var RetornoBQ = CargaBigQuery(Escopo.DatasetId, Escopo.TableId, ArqUnZipped[0]);
```

First two executions after finishing the code:
Loading status: RUNNING

Error message at third execution:
Error: API call to bigquery.jobs.insert failed with error: Empty response

The same files at the same tables. I was adjusting the console final messages before putting it on Apps Script scheduler.

The code is too simple and I am not seeing the elefant on the room.
Maybe it is something on BigQuery API access, but I have not changed anything.

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The Google Apps Script does not handle files larger than 50 Mb when uploadingo to Google BigQuery. The error message does not give a clue about that.

I have changed my script to split the file in pices lower than 50 Mb to upload to BigQuery.

Here follows the working code:

```
function cargaBigQuery(BQDatasetId, BQTableId, BQFileBlob) {
  // ================================================================================
  // Insere arquivo .csv no Google BigQuery.
  //
  // [BQDatasetId] = Dataset no BigQuery
  // [BQTableId] = Tabela no Dataset do BigQuery
  // [BQFileBlob] = Blob do arquivo CSV que será carregado
  // ================================================================================

  // ========================================
  // Define variáveis de escopo e arquivo

  const projectId = 'BIGQUERY PROJECT ID';
  BQFileBlob.setContentType('application/octet-stream');
  const tamanhoMaximo = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 50 MB em bytes

  var csvContent = BQFileBlob.getDataAsString("ISO-8859-1");
  var csvRows = csvContent.split("\r\n"); // dividir o conteúdo em linhas
  var cabecalho = csvRows.shift().split(";"); // remover a primeira linha e dividi-la em colunas
  var tamanhoAtual = 0;
  var divisoes = [[]];

  // ========================================
  // Divide o arquivo em blocos < 50 Mb

  csvRows.forEach(function(linha) {
    var tamanhoLinha = linha.length * 2; // tamanho em bytes
    if (tamanhoAtual + tamanhoLinha > tamanhoMaximo) {
      divisoes.push([]);
      tamanhoAtual = 0;
    }
    divisoes[divisoes.length - 1].push(linha.split(";"));
    tamanhoAtual += tamanhoLinha;
  });

  // ========================================
  // Cria a conexão no BigQuery

  var datasetId = BQDatasetId;
  var tableId = BQTableId;

  var dataset = BigQuery.Datasets.get(projectId, datasetId);
  if (!dataset) { 
    throw new Error("\t\tO dataset " + datasetId + " não existe."); 
  }

  var table = BigQuery.Tables.get(projectId, datasetId, tableId);
  if (!table) { 
    throw new Error("A tabela " + tableId + " não existe."); 
  }

  // ========================================
  // Realiza a carga no Big Query

  divisoes.forEach(function(divisao, indice) {
    var valores = [cabecalho].concat(divisao);
    var novoBlob = Utilities.newBlob(valores.join("\r\n"));

    var job = {
      configuration: {
        load: {
          destinationTable: {
            projectId: projectId,
            datasetId: datasetId,
            tableId: tableId
          },
          sourceFormat: "CSV",
          skipLeadingRows: 1,
          writeDisposition: "WRITE_APPEND",
          fieldDelimiter: ',',
          allowJaggedRows: true,
          allowQuotedNewlines: true,
          autodetect: false,
          ignoreUnknownValues: false,
          maxBadRecords: 0
        }
      }
    };

    try {
      var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, novoBlob);
      Logger.log("\t\t\tCarregando parte " + indice + " : " + jobResult.status.state);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('\t\tErro: Não consegui iniciar a carga no BigQuery: ' + err);
    }
  });
}
```

Note that I am in Brazil, so my file is ";" separated and the fields are quoted.