# Apps Script failed with error: Empty response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I moved all of my data in BigQuery to a specific region (europe-west2) a few weeks ago. Since then I keep getting "Empty Response" errors in all of my Apps Script that I've never had before, for example:

**API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Empty response**

Nothing else has changed except for the region change. The error is intermittent as well, to the point that I have created a workaround that literally tries the same "Bigquery.jobs.insert" immediately again, with a valid response.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening? Has anyone been having the same issue?

Thanks in advance
Dave

The problem is intermittent so literally running the exact same script and request will "fix" the problem. It is really hard to debug because it is intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some posts that this error points out that Google App script does not support uploading larger than 50 mb files. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75700323) a user splits the files into lower than 50 mb.

Also check this issue tracker for conversation about the same issue for your reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247052933